# Batch file: file mask

Tags: batch-file

I couldn't find details about how to use file mask in a batch file. My requirement,

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.log  -c "cmd /c somecommmand"
```

instead of selecting all the log files (*.log), how to select all the log files which has an integer suffix at the end. Eg, Among the following files,

```
test.log, test1.log, test2.log, test3.log..
```

I need a file mask to select ***all except***  `test.log`

I tried `test*.log`, but that slects test.log as well. It is preferrable to not include the file name part (test). something like, `*<0-9d>.log` .

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following, which I personally think is terrible, but it may just be what you need:

```
FOR %i IN (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ...) DO IF EXIST test%i.log (somecommand)
```

If the suffix is really *any* integer number in a potentially very large range, this won't work — unless you nest several `FOR` loops, where each takes care of only one digit, and you change the `IF EXIST test%i.log` to something like `IF EXIST test%a%b%c%d.log` (for four digits).

Also, there's no need to execute `somecommand` in a separate shell (`CMD /C`), unless of course that is in fact what you need to do.

Comment: *@Johannes Rössel:* That, kind Sir, would actually be waaaay smarter than what I suggested. ;-) (I've learnt something new today...)

Answer (score 2):

To match file names against a regular expression in a batch file you can use the following for loop as a template:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('"dir /B /S | findstr /E "\\test[0-9][0-9]*\.log""') do (
    echo %%I
)
```

This simply prints the full paths of all files in the current directory and its sub directories, whose name matches test1.log, test2.log, test3.log, ...

The `dir` command produces a listing of the directory tree from the current directory. Each line contains a full path. The listing is piped through the `findstr` command, which matches the full paths against the given regular expression. On each iteration the for variable `%%I` contains the full path of a file that has matched the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

As `test?.log` and even `test??.log` **will** find `test.log`, too, the only thing to get what you want would be some type of workaround, for example:

```
if exist test.log ren test.log test.tmp
REM Do your stuff here, you can now use test*.log
if exist text.tmp ren test.tmp test.log
```

I don't know if this unexpected behaviour of ? (not meaning exactly one character, but at most one character) is something Windows specific or was like this since DOS, but it can be very annoying.

Comment: thanks.. I could make it work this way, also you confirmed there is no regex kind of stuff in batch script.

Answer (score 0):

try `test?.log`

Comment: Won't work - you can try it in a shell: `echo > test.log; echo > test1.log; dir test?.log` will find 2 files.